# Electric field and potential in a point inside conductor for a particular case

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

Lets say we have an irregularly shaped conductor with a random cavity inside it and a charge +q outside the conductor. Now I have to find the potential inside the conductor due to induced charges on conductor and +q outside the conductor.
Now from the property of conductors with cavity, the field due to outer surface charges and outer charges is 0 inside the conductor. Since there will be a field outside the conductor due to +q and induced charge in outersurface, we cant say that line integral of field due to these two till the surface is not 0 and hence potential is not 0. Due to which potential due to these two is also not zero inside the conductor. Am I right?

Comment: Yes thank you it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no net E field inside the conductor.  If there were charges would move until it was gone.  The potential inside the conductor is constant, but not zero unless you choose  the conductor as your reference point for zero potential.